# is there any way in javascript to detect the language entered by the user in a text inpout box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am searching for if the javascript can hep in detect the language of a text,
 if its english, arabic,..etc. and based on this text direction will be change to the correct format.

Comment: You want to detect the browser's language setting via JavaScript or to detect the language of the text that the user enters?

Comment: for detecting browser's language see this plugin - https://github.com/dansingerman/jQuery-Browser-Language

Comment: @codingstill , the second.. to detect the language for a text user entered.

Comment: I see, don't think that there is such a feature. If you want to detect a few specific languages, you could build something on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript doesn't provide such a feature by default. You may find some libraries which can help you in doing so (to some some extent) or, the better option, via web services API. All you have to do in that latter case is to submit an AJAX request with the contents of the text box as data parameters and wait for the response. Based on the returned object you may detect the language by looking in the suitable field. Have a look here for some examples: http://detectlanguage.com/
To do AJAX interactions you can use JQuery: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: thank you for the useful answer and link (http://detectlanguage.com/ ).. i actually did search and felt that it can't be done via javascript, however this api is suffice ..